# Group by month using datetime field in zend 2

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am trying to get monthly transaction records according to location id. So I wrote following zend query to fetch data from the table. I want to get data by grouping according to both location id and month. But this query is not grouping properly in month but it groups according to the location id properly. Could you please help me to resolve this issue? Thanks.

```
        $oSelect = new Select($this->table());
        $oWhere  = new Where();
        $oWhere->equalTo('transaction.location_id',$aDataArray['location']);
        $oSelect->where($oWhere);
        $oSelect->group(array('location_id',new Expression('DATE_FORMAT(created_on, "%Y-%m")')));
        $aResults = $this->getTable()->selectWith($oSelect)->toArray();
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of getSqlString()?. From what I see you are grouping first by `location_id` and after that by `created_on`.

Comment: The group statement wouldn't be valid SQL, to group by the formatted `created_on` you would need to add the expression to the select with and alias, e.g  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('xyz','%Y-%m') as formatted_date`, then group by that alias `GROUP BY formatted_date`, although as there is no aggregated data you could just replace the `GROUP BY` with `SELECT DISTINCT`.